# How to update one database from another?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2008. I have two databases called `Adb` and `Bdb`. There is a common table called `commonTable`. How can I update `Adb` database every 15 minutes using the data from the same table in `Bdb`?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean. For example, do you want the contents of `Bdb` to completely overwrite `Adb` every time? Or are you more looking to merge (e.g. delete rows in A that have been deleted in B, update rows that have changed, insert rows that have been added)? If the latter, how do you identify a row in the tables? Can you provide schema and indicate the primary key?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without more specifics:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UpdateA
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE A 
    SET col1 = B.col1 /* , ... */
    FROM Adb.dbo.commonTable AS A
    INNER JOIN Bdb.dbo.commonTable AS B
    ON A.key_col = B.key_col;

  INSERT Adb.dbo.commonTable(key_col, col1 /* , ... */)
    SELECT key_col, col1 /* , ... */
    FROM Bdb.dbo.commonTable AS B
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Adb.dbo.commonTable
      WHERE key_col = B.key_col);

  DELETE A
    FROM Adb.dbo.commonTable AS A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Bdb.dbo.commonTable AS B
    ON A.key_col = B.key_col
    WHERE B.key_col IS NULL;
END
GO
```

Now schedule that stored procedure every 15 minutes using a [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) job.

Isolation, concurrency, error handling etc. are all additional considerations, but most concerns should be minor if this is the only process that writes to `Adb`. You might also consider a more concise [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command, but the syntax is daunting and it buys you less than you might expect in terms of improving concurrency and eliminating race conditions.

You might also want to consider [transactional replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151176.aspx) - get rid of this concept of having to do anything manually, and also the idea that data could be up to 15 minutes out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 database with tables. I want to update 2nd database table when there is an insert in first database table .
In first database when a row is inserted the values from that row shall get updated in second database table . (in first database table if employee_id and time  is inserted then the same update shall happen in the second database table for same employee_id )

Comment: If you have a new question, please don't use Answer section. Post it a separate [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)